# In Ruby, where is `Float(...)` documented?

Tags: ruby

In the Ruby language you can call `Float` like a function for robust way to ensure that the argument is a Float or a string parseable as a float (including scientific notation, etc).

For example:

```
Float(1.0)     # => 1.0
Float('1.0')   # => 1.0
Float('-1.23') # => -1.23
Float('-1e+2') # => -100.0
```

However, the Ruby docs don't seem to describe this behavior anywhere ([Float v2.1.0](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Float.html), [Float v1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html)).

Where can I find the documentation for this function?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Float.html)?

Comment: @JustinWood: no, I linked to that; I want to know where the `Float(...)` *function* is documented.

Comment: In any object Ruby allows you to have a method and constant with the same name, heuristically determining which to use by the context. For example, the `Nokogiri::XML` module is different from the `Nokogiri.XML()` method, though they appear to collide in the same named location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is defined here [Kernel#Float](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float). This function is part of the built-in conversion functions ( term coined by **Avdi Grimm** ) offered by ruby.

"*You really, really, want to convert an input object into a core type, no matter what the original type is. For instance, you need to ensure that any input is coerced into an Integer if there is any reasonable way to do so—whether the incoming data is a Float, a nil, or even a hexidecimal string.*
" **Confident Code, Avdi Grimm.**

For instance, using the [Kernel#Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) conversion function, imagine a method that takes 0 , 1 or more posts.

```
  def process_post(post_or_posts)
    posts = Array(post_or_posts)
    posts.each do |post|
      .... # do something post
    end
  end
```

This offered some flexibility when calling the method with varies inputs:

```
 process_post("post1")
 process_post(["post1", "post2"])
 process_post(nil)
```

If we were implementing this without the function we might have to do something like this:

```
 def process_post(post_or_post)
   if post_or_post    # now we have to check for nil
      # we might have to check for instance of Array to make sure we can iterate now.
      # etc..
   end
 end
```

This family of functions is certainly handy to create flexible API's.

Comment: +1 oh ya, I forgot about Kernel.  But now I'm confused about "Float" being both a class and a function...

Comment: @maerics it is sorted out by context.

Comment: @maerics I added some more info with a sample usage, perhaps this can clear it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your main question is you are using a method, but you don't where it has been implemented. Whenever I met such situation, I use [`Method#owner`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Method.html#method-i-owner) or [`#inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Method.html#method-i-inspect) to find out the source class name, where the method has been implemented. This is a a powerful method in this specific case.

```
method(:Float).owner # => Kernel 
method(:Float).inspect # => "#<Method: Object(Kernel)#Float>"
```

Then I use `ri` as `ri Kernel.Float` and read it in my *Konsole* :

```
= Kernel.Float

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Float(arg)    -> float

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns arg converted to a float. Numeric types are converted directly,
the rest are converted using arg.to_f. As of Ruby 1.8, converting nil
generates a TypeError.

  Float(1)           #=> 1.0
  Float("123.456")   #=> 123.456
```

Comment: @maerics Due to work, I forgot to add, what I now just added. Thanks for reminding me.. :-)